# Loading time in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have around 200000 data to be inserted into Oracle through SQL Developer from Excel. It is taking too much time to load 2,00000 scripts. I tried making some changes on tool--> preferences but no luck. Is there any way I can improve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 200.000 rows? That's not that much, shouldn't take long. What is really "too much time", if expressed in hours/minutes/seconds? BTW, did you read Jeff's *tutorial* (https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/). Alternatively, use SQL*Loader, if you know how. If not, we can help but - you'd have to post some sample data and target table description.

Comment: I tried import in batches with 1000 data. But it says GC overhead limit. Is there a way to import the 200000 data at once

Comment: We can't see your script, so how are we supposed to help?